# Add hash to url with filter in MixItUp

Tags: jquery, hash, jquery-isotope, mixitup

there's no documentation about the functionality I'd like to achieve and I'm unable to find it online, so I'm trying here.

I'd like to add a hash to the url when a user clicks on a filter. I'm using the [MixItUp](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/) jQuery plugin. Preferable it needs to remember the url hash with localstorage so if the user closes or refreshes the page, the filter the user has last clicked is still active.

[Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html#url-hash) has [the thing](http://s.codepen.io/desandro/debug/vErxXj#filter=%3Anot(.transition)) I want to achieve, but I can't get it to work in MixItUp, although it seems to be a similar technique? Maybe someone here has been able to get it to work.

I know how to add hash to url when the user clicks on a filter, but after refresh the active state resets to 'all'.

HTML for filter:

```
<section id="menu">
   <a id="one" class="filter menu-button active" data-filter="all">One</a>
   <a id="two" class="filter menu-button" data-filter=".selected:not(.button-exclude)">Two</a>
   <a id="three" class="filter menu-button" data-filter=":not(.selected)">Three</a>
 </section>`
```

JS for add hash:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#menu a").click(function(e) {
     window.location.hash = $(this).attr("id");
     e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit of a delayed reply, but I only come across this question now.

In order to initialise the filter based on a hash, I'll need a bit more HTML of your code for the filtered area. 
In the meantime, I copy my solution here, which works using the data-filter attribute. In my case I used classes to link the data-filter to the filterable elements.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="filtering">
  <span><a data-filter="all"><span>Show all</span></a></span>
  <ul>
    <li><a data-filter="._training-videos">Training Videos</a></li>
    <li><a data-filter="._how-to-guides">How-To Guides</a></li>
    <li style="display: none;"><a data-filter="all">Show all</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<section class="filter">    
  <article class="video _training-videos">
    <a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CY1wYKq5sLU?autoplay=1&amp;rel=0">
        <img src="/images/videos/CY1wYKq5sLU.jpg" />
    </a>
    <h4>What you need to know about online marketing</h4>
  </article>

  <article class="video _how-to-guides">
    <a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/L2QfjcgDjsY?autoplay=1&amp;rel=0">
        <img src="/images/videos/L2QfjcgDjsY.jpg" />
    </a>
    <h4>Handling, Cleaning, Playing your Vinyl</h4>
  </article>
</section>
```

The block at the top (div.filtering) is the filter dropdown (categories), while the bottom one (section.filter) is the area with images linked to YouTube videos.

In order to preload a filter, instead of initialising the MixItUp code like

```
$('.filter').mixItUp();
```

You'll need to use the { load: { filter: data_filter } } setting. 
This is obviously once you get the hashed value from the URL.

Here's the whole code snippet:

```
//  MixItUp init script
$(function () {
    //  Get the hash value from the URL
    var hashedValue = window.location.hash;
    if (hashedValue.replace('#', '') == '') {
        hashedValue = 'all';            //  Use the default filter if there's no hash value
    } else {
        hashedValue = '._' + hashedValue.replace('#', '');      //  Try to figure out the filter class based on the hash value
    }

    //  Make sure the filter dropdown selects the hash item
    $('.filtering').find('[data-filter="' + hashedValue + '"]').click();

    //  Init MixItUp
    $('.filter').mixItUp({
        load: {
            filter: hashedValue
        }
    });
});
```

Note, that you'll need to set the dropdown (.filtering) and the filterable area (.filter) separately.

Based on your code, I think the changes you need to make:

```
hashedValue = hashedValue.replace('#', '');
```

And

```
$('#menu').find('#' + hashedValue).click();
```

But I need your filtered area code to give you advice on that side of things.

Hope this helps, though. :)